# kafka after reboot cluster or os remove all connectors

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I use rest api for Kafka Connect. After reboot server all connectors are deleted and return result is empty.

```
curl -H "Accept:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors

output is : []
```

Comment: There's not enough information here. What commands are you using to start/stop the environment? If you used `confluent local`, or all Docker containers with no volumes, for example, all that data is temporary

Comment: @OneCricketeer  I don't use confluent or docker. simple config with this article https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-kafka-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: @OneCricketeer after reboot system all connectors are deleted. also kafka connect not working until run this commmand 
sudo /kafka/bin/connect-distributed.sh /kafka/config/connect-distributed.properties

Comment: Right. Kafka Connect doesn't start automatically with the brokers

Comment: You can also write a service unit file for Connect similar to Zookeeper or Kafka, as shown in that guide

Comment: @OneCricketeer This means that the connectors must be re-created after each reset server???

Comment: example create connector is : curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors/ -d '{"name":"inventory-connector","config":{"connector.class":"io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector","tasks.max":"1","database.hostname":"127.0.0.1","database.port":"3306","database.user":"root","database.password":"*****","database.server.id":"2","database.server.name":"test","database.include.list":"anikmlm","database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers":"127.0.0.1:9092","database.history.kafka.topic":"schema-changes.inventory"}}'

Comment: The curl command isn't relevant. If the Kafka topics are deleted, then, yes, you need to recreate the topics (done automatically with the connect-distributed script) and repost the connector. As answered, modify the Kafka (and Zookeeper) property files to store data in a persistent location

Answer (score 2):

Connectors are stored in Kafka topics

By default, Kafka (and Zookeeper) stores its topics/data under `/tmp`, which is wiped on restart

As mentioned in the comments, there are also other ways you'd end up with temporary data